# Implementation of itoa

Tags: performance, c, strings, integer, converting

```
int get_digits (int num)
{
   if(num < 10)
      return 1;

   if(num < 100)
      return 2;

    if(num < 1000)
      return 3;

    if(num < 10000)
      return 4;

    if(num < 100000)
      return 5;

    if(num < 1000000)
      return 6;

    if(num < 10000000)
      return 7;

    if(num < 100000000)
      return 8;

    if(num < 1000000000)
      return 9;

    return 10; /* num > 1000000000 */
}

char *itoa (int n)
{
    static char temp[10]; // MN that can be replaced by some def?
    int nDigits = 0;
    int i = 0;
 
    if(n == 0)
    {
        temp[0] = '0';
        temp[1] = '\0';
 
       return temp; // or just return "0"; ?
    }
 
    nDigits = get_digits(n); // fast function to count digits..
 
    temp[nDigits] = '\0'; // ..needed just here
 

   for(i = n; i >= 1; i /= 10) // whole method stinks
    {
        temp[--nDigits] = ((i % 10) + '0'); // modulo is quite slow
    }
 
    return temp;
}
```

This is my implementation of the infamous function `itoa()`, which isn't available everywhere and more importantly not available in my environment. Generally, the implementation of this function is ought to be different anyway. Performance and memory optimization is important.
This function converts an integer to a string. The function owns the reference to the returned string, which is statically allocated and the caller is responsible to make a copy of the returned string if he plans on changing it or preserving it across subsequent calls.

Comment: Some minor comments: You don't need to special case `n == 0` (since you will get the correct output with the rest of the code). `get_digits` (which should be completely eliminated) could possibly be improved a bit with some nested conditionals (`if (num < 100) return num < 10 ? 1 : 2;`), although smaller numbers will be more common that larger ones.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the loop at the bottom has `i >= 1`, therefore the special case for `n == 0` is indeed needed.

Comment: @RolandIllig Ah, I missed seeing that. However, you can easily change that loop into `i = n; do { ... } while ((i /= 10) >= 1);` to avoid the overhead of a probably rarely needed special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Interface

> ```
>     static char temp[10];
>     ⋮
>     return temp;
> ```

Returning a pointer to a `static` member can be a problem.  If clients aren't specifically warned, then they may inadvertently overwrite the storage before using it (consider `printf("%s%s", itoa(1), itoa(2))` as a minimal example).

In any case, such functions are not safely usable from multiple threads, and writing single-threaded code is an onerous limitation in the modern world.

One alternative is to allocate memory, but that obviously carries a huge performance penalty.

The usual approach for such functions is for the caller to pass appropriate storage.  The traditional interface is `void itoa(int n, char *buf)`, but I would strongly recommend updating to imitate `snprintf()` with something like `size_t itoa(int n, char *buf, size_t bufsize)` - where the return value represents the number of characters that *would* be written, even if greater than `bufsize`.

---

The `getdigits()` function shouldn't need external linkage, I think, so declare it `static`.

It returns `1` for all negative numbers.  The way to fix that is to convert all positive inputs to negative ones (note that the other way around does not work, since `-INT_MIN` isn't necessarily valid, but `-INT_MAX` always is).

```
int get_digits(int num)
{
    if (num > 0) {
        /* strip the leading '-' */
        return get_digits(-num) - 1;
    }

    if(num > -10)
       return 2;
    if(num > -100)
       return 3;
    ⋮
```

This function makes assumptions about `INT_MAX` which are not safe: If `INT_MAX` is less than 1000000000, then we have an undefined conversion, and if it's greater than 10000000000, we will return a value that's too small.

Since `INT_MAX` is guaranteed to be at least 10000, we can make a portable version:

```
int get_digits(int num)
{
    if (num > 0) {
        /* strip the leading '-' */
        return get_digits(-num) - 1;
    }

    int digit_count = 1;        /* leading '-' */
    while (num <= -10000) {
        digit_count += 4;
        num /= 10000;
    }

    if (num <= -100) {
        digit_count += 2;
        num /= 100;
    }

    if (num <= -10) {
        digit_count += 1;
    }

    return digit_count;
}
```

However, counting the digits in advance shouldn't be necessary - we can work backwards, then reverse the result in-place for less cost:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t itoa(int n, char *buf, size_t bufsize)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        if (bufsize > 1) {
            buf[0] = '0';
            buf[1] = '\0';
        }
        return 1;
    }

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t digits = 0;
    if (n < 0) {
        while (n) {
            int r = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            if (r > 0) {
                /* non-standard compiler */
                r -= 10;
                ++n;
            }
            if (buf && i < bufsize - 1) {
                buf[i++] = (char)('0' - r);
            }
            ++digits;
        }
        if (buf && i < bufsize - 1) {
            buf[i++] = '-';
        }
        ++digits;
    } else {
        /* n > 0 */
        while (n) {
            int r = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
            if (buf && i < bufsize - 1) {
                buf[i++] = (char)('0' + r);
            }
            ++digits;
        }
    }
    if (buf && i < bufsize - 1) {
        buf[i--] = '\0';
        /* reverse the output in-place */
        for (size_t j = 0;  j < i;  --i, ++j) {
            char c = buf[i];
            buf[i] = buf[j];
            buf[j] = c;
        }
    }

    return digits;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int test_itoa(const char *file, int line,
              int n, const char *expected)
{
    char buf[20];
    int result = 0;
    size_t actual = itoa(n, 0, 0);
    if (actual != strlen(expected)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: itoa(%d) returned %zu instead of %zu\n",
                file, line,
                n, actual, strlen(expected));
        result = 1;
    }
    actual = itoa(n, buf, sizeof buf);
    if (actual != strlen(expected)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: itoa(%d) returned %zu instead of %zu\n",
                file, line,
                n, actual, strlen(expected));
        result = 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(buf, expected)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: itoa(%d) produced %s instead of %s\n",
                file, line,
                n, buf, expected);
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

#define TEST_ITOA(n, s) test_itoa(__FILE__, __LINE__, n, s)

int main(void)
{
    return TEST_ITOA(0, "0")
        |  TEST_ITOA(1, "1")
        |  TEST_ITOA(10, "10")
        |  TEST_ITOA(12345, "12345")
        |  TEST_ITOA(-1, "-1")
        |  TEST_ITOA(-10, "-10")
        |  TEST_ITOA(-12345, "-12345")
        ;
}
```

Comment: Haha, love the 4 access violations `printf("%s%s", atoi(1), atoi(2))` :)
Easy to confuse itoa with atoi with those standard naming rules..

Comment: Er, yes - I think you know what I meant!  Now fixed.

Comment: While code readability due to formatting principles is more a matter of personal preference, I strongly encourage conforming to the UNIX philosophy in that functions should be as tiny as possible and doing just one thing. C as a functional programming language I find it for mandatory to work with up to 5 LOC functions. That in itself increases both readability and reusability, and also maintenance. You probably don't see it that way though

Comment: My rule of thumb is more like 24 lines - one standard screenful.

Answer (score 6):

The code almost works.

To make it work in all cases, test the program with Valgrind, which detects undefined behavior because of invalid memory access. This will prove that the buffer needs to be 11 bytes long, not only 10.

What about platforms where int has 64 bits instead of just 32? For these you need a larger buffer. Until then, you should use a *compile-time assertion* (static_assert) to ensure this implicit assumption.

What about negative numbers? -6 is a valid integer as well, and it should be converted appropriately.

If this function is the bottleneck of your whole program because it is too slow, have a look at how the Go programming language [converts integers to strings](https://golang.org/src/strconv/itoa.go). It's in the `strconv` package and uses lots of nice tricks to cut down the number of integer divisions, since that's the most expensive machine instruction in your code.

You can get rid of the `get_digits` function if you have the end of the string at a fixed address. Start with:

```
char *p = buf + sizeof buf - 1;
*p = '\0';
```

and then continue to fill the buffer from right to left by doing `*(--p) = '0' + digit`. At the end just `return p`, which will point to the first digit.

The return type should be `const char *` instead of `char *` since the caller is not supposed to do anything to the buffer.

Comment: I just don't like referring to "Go" in a way that suggests that I (or everyone) actually know this language and can read it. Please talk C

Comment: I provided you with the Go code as additional information because it is quite simple to read for a C programmer. In contrast, the C libraries often use hard to read code or just use the straight-forward, unoptimized algorithm: [NetBSD](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/1d3bf9c3887c1183e411dee14e1ba2e9d60de3e6/lib/libc/stdio/vsnprintf_ss.c#L398), [GNU libc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/_itoa.c.html#_itoa_word), which is quite boring for learning tricks.

Comment: I don't know, personally me, with over 10 years of experience in C, I am completely fine with the way C looks and feels. Also don't want to distract myself with Go, and make an effort to learn it, at least for now.